# Checkbox no longer checks if used with Jquery Toggle function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, toggle

I have a checkbox which, if checked, should enable some radio buttons below it.

If the checkbox is unchecked then the radio buttons below are disabled and, if they themselves  are checked, become unchecked.

To do this I have used the toggle function:

```
$( "#mycheckbox" ).toggle(function() {
    $('#radiobuttons input').attr('disabled', false);
}, function() {
    $('#radiobuttons input').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#radiobuttons input').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

However, now that my check box is being used in the Toggle function, it its self does not check.

To fix that I tried:

```
$( "#mycheckbox" ).toggle(function() {
    $('#radiobuttons input').attr('disabled', false);
    $("#mycheckbox").attr('checked','checked');
}, function() {
    $('#radiobuttons input').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#radiobuttons input').removeAttr('checked');
    $("#mycheckbox").removeAttr('checked');
});
```

But this too did not work.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/P95xg/3/

Jquery Version: 1.4.3

HTML:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="Y" />
    <span><strong> Label text here </strong></span>
</label>

<div id="radiobuttons">
<label class="hit"><input type="radio" name="accommodation" value="Standard Room Cat 1" />
    <span>
        <strong>Standard Room Category 1 </strong>
    </span>
    </label>

    <label class="hit"><input type="radio" name="accommodation" value="Standard Room Cat 2" />
    <span>
        <strong>Standard Room Category 2 </strong>
    </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: can you edit the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P95xg/1/ to recreate the issue

Comment: @ArunPJohny added HTML and JQ version above

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have updated the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P95xg/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using .change() instead of toggle()

```
var $radios = $('#radiobuttons input');
$("#mycheckbox").change(function (e) {
    $radios.attr('disabled', !this.checked);
    if(!this.checked){
        $radios.removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P95xg/)

Note: Still didn't find the reason for the said behavior

Comment: Thanks but I cant - my version of Jquery doesnt support it

Comment: @MeltingDog it is working with jQuery 1.4.3 - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P95xg/6/

Answer (score 0):

The `toggle` function is used to show and hide elements.

My advice would be to add an event handler to the checkbox which checks if the checkbox is checked and then enables or disables the radio buttons.

Something like this:

```
(function () {
    // Store our radio buttons and checkbox:
    var radioButtons = $('#radiobuttons input'),
        checkbox = $('#checkbox');

    // Add an event handler:
    checkbox.on('change', function () {
        // When our checkbox is checked, the radioButtons become active:
        radioButtons.prop('disabled', !checkbox.prop('checked'));
    });
}());
```

Comment: Thanks - this is a good answer, but .prop() isnt compatible with my version of JQ